# Selenium only executes if != null part of loop, and does not run the "else if null " part of the loop

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a if-else statement where:

condition 1: ID matches and certain fields are auto-populated. Then the if statement only fills rest of the remaining fields

condition 2: ID does not match, all fields are blank. ELSE statements fills them all

When I make condition 1 true, code runs If statement and works correctly.
When I make condition 2 true, code again run what the If statement should do rather than the else statement

I am using Selenium Java for the automation.

I have tried putting individual if-else statements for each field object, I have tried alternating between if != null, if !field.equals(null). I have also tried doing field.gettext(), assigning it to a variable and checking variable.length != 0.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.name("city")) != null) {

    object.setField6;
    object.setField7;
    object.setField8;
    object.setField9;

} else {

    object.setField2;
    object.setField3;
    object.setField4;
    object.setField5;
    object.setField6;
    object.setField7;
    object.setField8;
    object.setField9;
}
```

I picked a random address field for my if statement.

```
if (cityField != null) {

     Only fill the three remaining fields

} else {

     Fill all 8 fields (i.e. including address fields)

}
```

When I run this, and put a valid id number, the if statement works correctly. But when I put an invalid id, which leaves the "cityField" null, the if statement executes instead of the "else" statement and only populates 3 fields instead of all 8.

This is all I am doing inside the object methods for each field:

```
method() {
  city.click();
  city.sendKeys(cityName); 
}
```

Comment: I would assume that the page has the element, the value of the element is not being checked with `driver.findElement(By.name("city"))` - just that it is present.

Comment: `only populates 3 fields` by this do you mean only 3 fields got filled with values? what is the purpose of checking this > `driver.findElement(By.name("city")) 1=null` ? does this check means you only seeing 3 fields? question is not clear enough

Comment: @Dev No, I see all 9 fields in both cases. Only difference is when ID is valid, 4 address fields are automatically populated (so I don't want to touch that). For this reason, I am only populating the remaining fields (user related), and leaving the address fields alone. For the ELSE statement, the ID is invalid, so I want to populate all the fields, including address fields

Comment: so when user ID is valid the address information of that user is got auto populated ?

Comment: driver.findElement returns a WebElement. Are you sure you're validating the value of the field/WebElement and not the element itself? (e.g. WebElement element = driver.findElement(...); String value = element.getText()). Probably you want to check whether the value is null or empty and not the WebElement.

Comment: @Dev Yes address fields are auto populated

Comment: @Apostolos I have tried that as well. 
  String text = driver.findElement(By.name("city")).getText();

  if (text.length() != 0) { Only fill remaining fields } else { fill all fields

Comment: Also, I tried putting both conditions in separate if statements (as if that matters) and only the first if statement is getting called, when either of the conditions meet

Comment: @Mysa123 can you add the html structure of the city field? are you getting auto populated text for this field?

Comment: @Dev, yes, but will only auto-populate if ID is a match in the system. Otherwise it will be empty for me to enter. <input type="text" name="city_id11" value="" class="form-control city isRequired" onchange="rerendercompanypanel('all');">

Comment: I would suggest to print the element.getText() so that you see the value causing your code not to get into the else block. This might help you understand the root cause of the issue you're facing.

Comment: `findElement` will never return null.

Comment: @Mysa123 any errors you getting on this line `driver.findElement(By.name("city"))` i don't see name as city it has "city_id11" and it may  be raising exception check this element if you getting or not before entering into if statement

Comment: @ApostolosEmmanouilidis thanks for the suggestion! Don't know why it never occurred to me to print to console and check. Figured out the issue. GetText was not grabbing the auto populated value. But getAttribute("value") did the trick. Code is working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (driver.findElements(By.name("city")).size() > 0) {

                object.setField6;
                object.setField7;
                object.setField8;
                object.setField9;

            } else {

                object.setField2;
                object.setField3;
                object.setField4;
                object.setField5;
                object.setField6;
                object.setField7;
                object.setField8;
                object.setField9;
            }
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
         try   {
                driver.findElement(By.name("city"));
                object.setField6;
                object.setField7;
                object.setField8;
                object.setField9;

               } catch(WebDriverException wde)
            {
                object.setField2;
                object.setField3;
                object.setField4;
                object.setField5;
                object.setField6;
                object.setField7;
                object.setField8;
                object.setField9;
            }
```